# Add a css class to a Joomla site

Tags: css, joomla3.0, web-inspector

I'm trying to change the style of a module in a Joomla template.
As a first step I created my class and tested it on google inspector.
Then I applied the new class directly on the css by simply using the inspector editor, just to see its effectiveness.
Finally, when I put the change on the real css and save it on Joomla panel nothing happens, refreshing the page and looking newly through the inspector, css script seems not to be modified.
What could the problem be referred to?

Comment: You might need to clear your browser or server cache for the changes to show up. You can test it by going to your site and adding `?cache_bust=true` (or really any query string) to the URL and see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing so doesn't make the applied changes visible. It seems like the css doesn't change at all.

Comment: Thank you, now it works well especially if used in addition to hide navigation windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jimi please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.